# What hub to purchase for a GT aggressor?

Tags: hub, freewheel

I have a GT Aggressor 1.0

Specs here: http://www.gtbicycles.com/2013/bikes/mountain/trail/aggressor-1-0

Recently on a long ride, the crank started to roll freely after a long downhill.  i.e. when pedaling, the cycled does not move because the rear freewheel simply rolled freely without engaging.  I think the problem is with the rear hub which may need to be replaced.

From looking at the specs, the hub is a "Alloy Cassette Disc QR".  Trying to find it at amazon.com, there were so many to chose from and did not know which one to purchase to replace this.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks you!

Comment: You can try to overhaul the hub first-more simply, the pawls are stuck and a light lubricant can free them. You'll be able to buy some more usage, but it is a generic disc hub and may not be easily overhauled. Depending on how much use the bike has seen, it might be more cost effective to buy a pre-built wheel...just make sure you match the rotor mount, rim diameter, and rim width. It will be a 135mm O.L.D. hub which fits most mountain bikes.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of wheels that will fit that bike, and they may very well be less expensive than having the hub overhauled.

You want to find a 26 inch wheel with an 8/9 speed cassette compatible hub, with 32 spokes ( that's the 32H part )

I actually don't see any on Amazon.com that fit the bill. This is one of those times I would head into the local bike shop to make the wheel replacement process quick and easy.

Comment: I live in a city in India where there are no local bike shops that stock the wheels or these hubs, hence looking at online store to shop them over.  If I get a new compatible hub, I can get a bike mechanic to install it.

These are two hubs I located on Amazon that may bit my wheel.  They are 32H, Rear hub with Disk.  Do you agree?

http://goo.gl/DXyv3

http://goo.gl/o5O7e

Thanks!

Comment: Yes by all means if you have a mechanic who can install the hub that would be a much less expensive route to take.